# Molecular addon not working?

Tags: add-on

I am using molecular script ad-on but every time I try making molecular simulation the "Start simulation" button is unusable and says process... simulating.. left...
I have tried different simulations and tried creating new projects but it always says the same thing 
[image]

If anyone knows what is happening please let me know...

Comment: Having the same problem...

Comment: I’ve had similar problems in the past following interrupted simulations. I found the best way forward in this situation was to save my file, close Blender, reopen and re-load (alternatively you might get away with Save followed by Revert - it’s a while since I hit this and can’t remember). This should reset the state of the add-on and should allow you to re-run the simulation.

Comment: Tried that multiple times, tried allso creating brand new project, still nothing...